# Conservar valor en un input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo una inquietud lo que pasa que estoy desarrollando una interfaz donde el usuario insertara en un input un porcentaje y lo que deseo hacer es que el input en automático me agregue el % después de que se inserten los dígitos o si tiene ya el % lo mantenga no se si me di a entender, Gracias, Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes valerte de los eventos del `input`; por ejemplo, el evento `onchange` se dispara cuando se abandona el elemento, siempre que su valor haya cambiado mientras mantuvo el foco.

En la función que se llama al disparar el evento, en el ejemplo a continuación, evalúo si hay algún contenido en el input, y si lo hay, si el último caracter es un `%`. Si no lo es, se lo agrego.

```js
document.body.innerHTML = `
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="numero">Porcentaje</label>
    <input id="numero">
    <button type="submit">procesar</button>
  </div>
</form>
`;

//primero, necesitamos una referencia al input
let numInput = document.getElementById('numero');

numInput.addEventListener('change',()=>{
  console.log("evaluando");
  let contenido = numInput.value;
  if (contenido!='') {
    if (contenido.slice(-1)!='%') { 
      console.log("agregando %");
      numInput.value = contenido + '%';
    }
  } else {
    console.log("vacío");
  }
});
```

El código de la vida real debiera ser, probablemente, más robusto en el sentido de agregar el símbolo solo si se ingresó un número válido, por ejemplo... lo que se acomode a tu caso de uso ya depende de las particularidades del mismo.

Comment: Gracias jachguate, creo si utilizare esta solucion el manejo de eventos, se acomoda a mi proyectos gracias

Answer (score -1):

Si lo que quieres es dejar el valor del porcentaje  en el input puedes probar dejando el signo porcentaje en el value

Comment: Por favor, lee [answer]